# can the null space contain more elements that {0} if the map is a function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

can the null space have more elements than $\{0\}$ if T is a function but not necesarily linear?

For example, For the map

$$T(a_1,a_2)\mapsto (\sin a_1,0)$$ would'nt it be the case that if $T$ were linear then only $T(0,0)$ maps to (0,0), so showing two distinct elements that map to (0,0) should prove non-linearlity?  I do have another way off proving that the map is'nt linear

$$T(2\dfrac{\pi}{2},0)= (0,0)$$ but factoring out the $2$ maps $T$ to $(2,0)$.  So I'm just wondering if the first proof I wrote is sufficient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are also linear maps whose null space is more than just $\{0\}$.

Comment: It may be, John, that you are not very clear on the concepts you require on these topics. What you name Null space has a well-known structure in linear algebra and serves to characterize the linear function to which it is associated. Regards.

Comment: If you mean to talk about maps of vector spaces, then a linear map $T$ has a null space of $\{0\}$ if and only if $T$ is injective. So, showing that the null space of a map is non trivial does not show that the map is non linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up some concepts.

To clarify a bit: a *linear* mapping  $T: V \rightarrow W$ over a field $K$ satisfies the following conditions.  For all $u,v \in V$ and any scalar $\alpha \in K$

1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$
2. $T(\alpha v) = \alpha T(v)$

Now, to your questions.

> can the null space have more elements than {0} if T is a function
>   but not necessarily linear?

Yes, there are many linear mappings that have more elements in the null space than just $\{ 0\}$. That's why the concepts of null spaces and ranges are so important in linear algebra.

> would'nt it be the case that if T were linear then only $T(0,0)$maps to $(0,0)$, so showing two distinct elements that map to $(0,0)$ should prove non-linearlity?

No. If a linear mapping $T$ has more elements in the null space than just $\{ 0\}$ it just means that the mapping is not *injective*. It does **not** mean it's not linear.

Comment: So it's injectivty that's implied by the null space = {0}.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, that's correct. A linear mapping $T$ is injective $\iff$ $N(T) = \{ 0 \}$ , where $N(T)$ is the null space of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

If we stick with the commonly accepted meaning of common terms, then unfortunately your question doesn't make much sense.

First of all, if $T$ is a function, even between vector spaces, that is not linear, then we can't speak of its "null space". You're actually talking about the preimage of zero: for $T:V\to W$, you seem to be asking about $T^{-1}(0_W)=\{v\in V:T(v)=0_W\}$. This is guaranteed to be a vector subspace of $V$ only if $T$ is linear, in which case it is known as the *null space* or the *kernel* of $T$. But if $T$ is not linear, then it's usually **NOT** a subspace, just a subset, and so we wouldn't call it "the null space".

Moreover, for general functions the preimage of zero may contain not only *more* than just $\{0\}$, but also ***less*** than $\{0\}$, or something completely different at all. For example, consider the following nonlinear functions $T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ between one-dimensional real vector spaces:

- $T(x)=x^2+1$, where $T^{-1}(0)=\varnothing$ is "less" than $\{0\}$;
- $T(x)=x^2-5x+6$, where $T^{-1}(0)=\{2,3\}$ is "more" (?) than just $\{0\}$, except for it doesn't even contain zero.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying where I misunderstood the null space.  makes sense now!